# When I have an a function that produces and object containing functions, how can I get it to load those functions directly?

Tags: r, function

I have created a function `generate_functions` that outputs a list containing other functions --- it gives an output that has a structure that looks something like this:

```
#Generate an object using a generating function
MY_FUNCTION <- generate_functions(data, bandwidth = 1)

#Show the structure of the output
#This is a list containing four functions
str(MY_FUNCTION)
List of 4
 $ dkde     :function (x, bandwidth = 1, log = FALSE)  
 $ pkde     :function (x, bandwidth = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)  
 $ qkde     :function (p, bandwidth = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)  
 $ rkde     :function (n, bandwidth = 1)
```

Obviously, I can call the output functions by calling `MY_FUNCTION$dkde`, `MY_FUNCTION$pkde`, etc.  However, I would like to be able to call these functions directly using `dkde`, `pkde`, etc. (i.e., without having to refer to elements of the initial object).  Ideally I would like to add a logical option to my function `generate_functions` that loads each of the four output functions so that they can be called directly.

**Question:** What changes can I make to the internal code for `MY_FUNCTION` so that it loads the four output functions to allow me to refer to them directly?

Comment: You can do `attach(MY_FUNCTION)` to change the namespace so that you can refer to them directly.

Comment: Try `list2env(MY_FUNCTION, .GlobalEnv)`.